# Sobrecargar constructor en clase heredada

Tags: java, constructor, sobrecarga

Tengo una clase Persona que tiene el siguiente constructor

```
Person(String firstName, String lastName, int identification){
```

Y una clase estudiante que extiende de Persona y a cuyo constructor le quiero anadir un parametro mas, que son las notas. Para ello, extiendo y creo un nuevo constructor

```
class Student extends Person{
private int[] testScores;

Student(String firstName, String lastName, int identification, int[] numScores){
```

El problema es que el compilador me da un error aqui, debido a:

constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types, requiered String, String,int.

Vamos que no sobrecarga el constructor de la clase Persona y me sigue indicando que el constructor de Persona solo tiene 3 argumentos.

Como puedo solucionar este error?
Es para un ejercicio y no puedo crear un nuevo constructor en la clase Persona con los 4 argumentos, sino que tiene que ser un constructor en la clase estudiante.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Sobrecárgalo así:

```
Student(String firstName, String lastName, int identification, int[] numScores){
    super(firstName, lastName, identification);
    this.testScores = numScores;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Student extends Person{
private int[] testScores;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int identification, int[]numScores){
  super(firstName, lastName, identification);
  this.testScores= numScores;
}
```

Con `super()`, llamas al constructor del padre y con `this.testScores= numScores;` añades el nuevo atributo de la clase Student

Comment: `Con super(), heredas el constructor del padre` quizás quieras revisar esto.

Comment: con `super()` llamas al contructor por defecto. Deberías llamar al que ya tiene creado con los tres argumentos.

Comment: Cierto, lo modifico

Comment: Gracias, mi solución funcionaba, pero esta es mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber encontrado la respuesta.

El problema es que no tenia definido un constructor por defecto.
He creado el constructor Persona(){} y el error en la clase student ha desaparecido.

Answer (score 0):

Los constructores **NO SE HEREDAN**. Por eso se puede hacer sobrecarga sólo entre constructores de la misma clase (por ejemplo, entre dos `Student(...)`).

Eso sí, lo primero que hace cada constructor es llamar al constructor de la clase padre<sup>1</sup>. Se puede hacer explícitamente con `super([parámetros])`, pero si no lo haces tú el constructor lo hace implícitamente llamando al constructor por defecto.

El problema aquí es que no existe un constructor por defecto en la clase padre, por lo que tendrás que hacer explícita la llamada (recuerda, debe ser *la primera instrucción*).

```
Student(
  String firstName,
  String lastName,
  int identification,
  int[] numScores){

  super(
    firstName,
    lastName,
    identification);
  ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Y lo primero que hará el constructor de la clase padre es llamar a un constructor de su clase padre, así hasta llegar a `Object`.